# Проблема с GVariant

Tags: linux, c, glib, gio

Получаю от сигнала GVariant. Тип пишет (x), я посмотрел что x это INT64. Я пишу такой код.

```
void handle_seek ( GDBusConnection *con,
                const gchar *sender_name,
                const gchar *object_path,
                const gchar *interface_name,
                const gchar *signal_name,
                GVariant *param,
                gpointer data ) {
        const gchar *type = g_variant_get_type_string ( param );
        printf ( "type:%s\n", type );
        gint64 pos = g_variant_get_int64 ( param );
        printf ( "pos:%ld\n", pos );
}
```

Но он пишет ошибку такую.

```
type:(x)

(process:3952): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:06:24.806: g_variant_get_int64: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT64)' failed
pos:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Тип пишет (x), я посмотрел что x это INT64.

`x` — это INT64, а `(x)` — это кортеж (*tuple*) состоящий из одного значения INT64 (смотри [документацию](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariantType.html#id-1.6.18.6.9)). т.е. обращаться с ним нужно как-то так:

```
    GVariant *child = g_variant_get_child_value (param, 0);
    assert (child);
    gint64 pos = g_variant_get_int64 (child);
    g_variant_unref (child);
```